# Bug ao iniciar tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Boa noite pessoal,

Comecei a estudar o livro da casa do código, spring mvc, porém logo de cara travei no seguinte erro ao tentar iniciar o tom cat, alguem consegue ajudar?

```
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:casadocodigo' did not find a matching property.
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server built: Jan 10 2017 21:02:52 UTC
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server number: 8.5.11.0
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name: Windows 10
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version: 10.0
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture: amd64
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version: 1.8.0_111-b14
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE: C:\Users\marco\WebJava\worksplaces\aprendendoWeb.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME: C:\Users\marco\WebJava\Server\tomcat 8
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\marco\WebJava\worksplaces\aprendendoWeb.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\marco\WebJava\Server\tomcat 8
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\marco\WebJava\worksplaces\aprendendoWeb.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\marco\WebJava\Server\tomcat 8\endorsed
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\marco\WebJava\Server\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Users\marco\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\marco\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\marco\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\marco\WebJava\IDE\eclipse JEE;;.
jan 23, 2017 9:19:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 976 ms
jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Catalina
jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/casadocodigo]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/casadocodigo]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@3f14391b]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4974)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@1445e33a]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:708)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:111)
... 13 more

jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more

jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMAÇÕES: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMAÇÕES: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Stopping service Catalina
jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
jan 23, 2017 9:19:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: Parece ser problema de arquivo corrompido. Supondo que o app "casadocodigo" seja um war que você baixou, sugiro refazer o download.

Comment: @Badaro consegui resolver o problema excluindo o repository do maven, e atualizando as dependências para as mais recentes.

Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Aqui no SOpt não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia a todos!

O problema foi resolvido excluído o repository do maven, e fazendo download de todas as dependências novamente.

Obrigado!